# Passing in Arguments to Kubernetes Deployment Pod

Tags: cron

I'm trying to create a kubernetes deployment that creates a pod.

I want this pod to run the command "cron start" on creation so that cron is automatically initialized.

This is currently how I am trying to run the command though it clearly isn't working (kubernetes_deployment.yaml)

```
    - containerPort: 8080
    command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
    args: ["cron start"]
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Kubernetes CronJobs.
You can set a cron expression.

https://kubernetes.io/es/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```